# How to return a different value when what() is called in an exception class hierarchy with parameter

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to get a different value when I call the class ReferenceGoodException.
For example, i give the class "bob", I want "bob is good" in return
ReferenceException.h

```
  class ReferenceException : public std::runtime_error
  {
  public:
    ReferenceException (const std::string& p_reason);
  };
```

ReferenceException.c++

```
ReferenceException::ReferenceException (const std::string& p_reason) : std::runtime_error (p_reason) { }
```

ReferenceGoodException.h

```
class ReferenceGoodException : public ReferenceException
  {
  public:
    ReferenceDejaPresenteException (const std::string& p_reason);
  };
```

ReferenceGoodException.c++

```
  ReferenceGoodException ::ReferenceGoodException (const std::string& p_reason) : ReferenceException (p_reason) { }
```

main.cpp

```
int main () {
  try
    {
      throw ReferenceGoodException("bob");
    }
  catch (ReferenceGoodException& e)
    {
      std::cout << e.what () << std::endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For your problem, one possible solution is to have the exception class construct the string, store it in a `std::string`, which is then passed on to the parent exception class.

Comment: By the way, what is `ReferenceGoodException` supposed to be used for? What kind of exceptional errors can happen because of a "good" reference?

Comment: I named it randomly. For the moment it's just a random exception. I will of course change it later

Answer (score 0):

```
  ReferenceGoodException ::ReferenceGoodException (const std::string& p_reason) : ReferenceException (p_reason + "is good") { }
```